# Laravel HasMany relation with parameters

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have a relation between User model and Friend model

User.php

```
    public function friends()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Friend::class);
    }
```

the relation actually returns  all the records where the foreign key column (user_id) between User and Friend equals the current user's id but i want to return also the records where current user's id is in another column in friends table which's name is friend_id, this is my try

```
    public function friends()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Friend::class,'user_id','friend_id');
    }
```

it's actually not returning the correct records

Comment: Can you share your DB structure as well?

Comment: i am sorry i can't share but it's a one to many relationship between User and Friend through a foreign key named(user_id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct way to that but you could try making 2 relations and merge them into one relation

```
public function friends() {
    return $this->hasMany(Friend::class);
}

public function additionalfriends() {
    return $this->hasMany(Friend::class, 'friend_id');
}

public function allfreinds() {
    return $this->friends->merge($this->additionalfriends);
}
```

another solution you might try is

```
public function friends()
{
    return Friend::where(function($query) {
        $query->where('user_id',$this->id)
            ->orWhere('friend_id',$this->id);
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer @Mohamed Naguib there is no way to do it in a same function as a relation ?

Answer (score 0):

Use This

// User Model

```
 public function tasks(){
    return $this->hasMany(TaskUser::class,'user_id','id')->latest();
}
```

//UserTask Model

```
public function task(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Task::class,'task_id','id');
}
```

//Controller

```
$user = User::with(['tasks' => function ($query) {
            $query->with('task');
        }])->find(auth('api')->id());
        return $this->successResponse(data:
        TaskResource::collection($user->tasks->pluck('task')->where('dueDate',"2021-09-07")),
            message:'Success',code:200
        );
```

I hope it is useful